# How to make lightning effect on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was wondering on how to make the following lightning around that sprite.
I've tried a thin pencil and outer glow but it just doesn't have that effect.

Below are the things I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are 4 pictures above with different lightning styles, it'd be great if someone can tell me how to add it on.

I assume it's just a pencil brush or something.

Answer (score 1):

In general...

A base color, then the **Overlay** blending mode - either on a new layer or as a tool setting. Paint white in `Overlay` above the color and the "neon-like" color starts to appear. Repeat layers for additional color boosts.

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice way, but on the examples I've shown, they don't seem to have have that overlay/neon effect. Is there any other way? I've tried downloading lightning brushes, but that is just one single lightning.

The problem is that I can't seem to get that thinless and colour of the examples I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way -

Have a Empty layer, double click on the layer, go in effects and add outer glow to it, press ok to save the effect.

Paint with the brush tool on your layer or pen tool the desirable shape of lighting you want. (Make sure your brush is White colour)

[image]

I'm very sure there is many in-depth references on the internet with video tutorials.

Comment: Outerglow? And their way doesn't seem like it's a pencil, maybe it's a lightning render or something?

Comment: Outglow correct, change the colour to purple or what colour you would like